# Avoiding encapsulated mail in java mail API

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I have written code checking the mail fetching the recipients calculating their lengths and based on that calculation forwarding the mail to the same id, its all working fine, but my mail is forwarded as attached mail. i don't want that. i want simple mail to be forwarded.

Please suggest where i am lacking

```
public class CheckingMail {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String host = "mycompanyname.com";
       String mailStoreType = "pop3";
       String username = "myemailid.com"; 
       String password = "mypassword";
       check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);
  }

 public static void check(String host, String mailStoreType,String username, String password) {

  try {
     System.out.println("\n\n1 creating the properties field");
   //create properties field
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);   //The POP3 server to connect to.
        properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
        properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");

         // Get a Session
             Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(properties);
        System.out.println("\n\n2 Get a Session="+emailSession);
        System.out.println("\n\n3 create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server");
      //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
        Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");
       // Store store = emailSession.getStore(mailStoreType);
        store.connect(host,username,password);
        System.out.println("\n\n4create the folder object and open it");
      //create the folder object and open it
        Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        System.out.println("\n\n5 retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it");
     // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
        Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
        System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);
        System.out.println("\n before for loop");
        for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
           Message message = messages[i];
           // MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(emailSession);
            System.out.println("---------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Email Number =" + (i + 1));
            //System.out.println("To Recipients =" +  message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
            System.out.println("Subject = " + message.getSubject());
            System.out.println("From =" + message.getFrom()[0]);
           // System.out.println("Text =" + message.getContent().toString());
         /*=====================  To and CC starts here ===============================*/
            Address[] address;
               StringBuffer msg_buffer_to = new StringBuffer(50);
     // TO
     if ((address = message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)) != null) {
      for (int j = 0; j < address.length; j++) {
       msg_buffer_to.append(address[j]);

       System.out.println("\t\t\tTO " + address[j]);


      }

     }
     StringBuffer msg_buffer_cc = new StringBuffer(50);
     // CC
     if ((address = message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC)) != null) {
      for (int j = 0; j < address.length; j++) {
       msg_buffer_cc.append(address[j]);

       System.out.println("\t\t\tCC " + address[j]);

      }

     }

     //counting the length here for both To and CC...


    System.out.println("\n\n\t total length is== "+(msg_buffer_to.length()+msg_buffer_cc.length())+"\n\n");

    /*************************************Merging of forward class***********************************************************/

     if((msg_buffer_to.length()+msg_buffer_cc.length())>100)
     {
      System.out.println("\n\t Address length crossed the limits\t\n");
      //forward mailing starts here 

     // Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
           properties.put("mail.pop3s.host", "mycompanyname.com");
           properties.put("mail.pop3s.port", "995");
           properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
           properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
           properties.put("smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
           properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "mycompanyname.com");
           properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

               Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
           protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
               return new PasswordAuthentication("mymailid.com","mypassword");  
           }  
         });
      try{
       // session.setDebug(true);
             // Get a Store object and connect to the current host

             // Create a Folder object and open the folder
             Folder folder = store.getFolder("inbox");
             folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

             if (messages.length != 0) {


                // Get all the mail ids from the message

                String from = InternetAddress.toString(message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
                if (from != null) {
                    System.out.println("From:"  + from);
                }

                String to = InternetAddress.toString(message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
                if (to != null) {
                   System.out.println("To: " + to);             
                }
                String subject = message.getSubject();
                if (subject != null) {
                   System.out.println("Subject: " + subject);
                }

                   Message forward = new MimeMessage(session);
                   // Fill in header

                   forward.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("mymailid.com"));
                   forward.setSubject("Fwd: " + message.getSubject());

                   forward.addFrom(InternetAddress.parse(from));
                   forward.setFrom(new InternetAddress("mymailid.com"));      

                   // Create the message part
                   MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                   // Create a multipart message
                   Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                   // set content
                   messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "message/rfc822");
                   // Add part to multi part
                   multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                   // Associate multi-part with message
                   forward.setContent(multipart);
                   forward.saveChanges();
                   Transport.send(forward);
                   // Send the message by authenticating the SMTP server
                   // Create a Transport instance and call the sendMessage
                   System.out.println("message forwarded successfully....");
              //  }          // end if
          //  }


      }// end if

         catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();  
     }

     }

         }

      //close the store and folder objects
        System.out.println("\n\n6 close the store and folder objects");    
        emailFolder.close(false);
        store.close();
        } catch (MessagingException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
 }![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPe3t.jpg)
```

Comment: What do **you** mean by "forwarded"?  The JavaMail FAQ has information on [how to forward a message](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#forward).

Comment: Mails are getting forwarded as encapsulated mails or we can say as an attached mail...But I want to forward them as simple text mails....I have tried that link but no use...

Comment: What exactly have you tried?  What result did you get?  What result are you trying to get?  Show us the code you're using and an example of what you want it to do.

Comment: This is complete code....When we forward any mail simply I want that only.....But when I am forwarding mails those mails are getting forwarded as an attachment....

Comment: Hi...Yes done it...I forgot to add message.getContent()...Now working fine...Thanks...

Comment: @Navi, you should post your solution as answer - you can also accept it. Then, when someone looks at this question, it looks answered and he can quicly see solution, with no need to read all the comments.

Comment: i have already posted correct answer that it needs to get added just message.getContent()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sorry i am bit late for posting the complete solution for forwarding the mail on the basis of character length as the text mail instead of attached mail. Consider this as accepted answer. I hope it serves the purpose.**

```
public class CheckingMail {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
           String host = "mycompanyname.com";
           String mailStoreType = "pop3";
           String username = "myemailid.com"; 
           String password = "mypassword";
           check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);
      }

    public static void check(String host, String mailStoreType,String username, String password) {
    try {
         System.out.println("\n\n1 creating the properties field");
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);   //The POP3 server to connect to.
            properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
            properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");

            Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(properties);
            System.out.println("\n\n2 Get a Session="+emailSession);
            System.out.println("\n\n3 create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server");

            Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");
            store.connect(host,username,password);
            System.out.println("\n\n4create the folder object and open it");
            Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            System.out.println("\n\n5 retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it");
            Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
            System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);
            System.out.println("\n before for loop");
            for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
               Message message = messages[i];
               System.out.println("Email Number =" + (i + 1));
               System.out.println("Subject = " + message.getSubject());
               System.out.println("From =" + message.getFrom()[0]);
               Address[] address;
               StringBuffer msg_buffer_to = new StringBuffer(50);

         if ((address = message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)) != null) {
          for (int j = 0; j < address.length; j++) {
           msg_buffer_to.append(address[j]);
           System.out.println("\t\t\tTO " + address[j]);
          }
         }
         StringBuffer msg_buffer_cc = new StringBuffer(50);
         if ((address = message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC)) != null) {
          for (int j = 0; j < address.length; j++) {
           msg_buffer_cc.append(address[j]);
           System.out.println("\t\t\tCC " + address[j]);
          }
         }
        System.out.println("\n\n\t total length is== "+(msg_buffer_to.length()+msg_buffer_cc.length())+"\n\n");

         if((msg_buffer_to.length()+msg_buffer_cc.length())>100)
         {
          System.out.println("\n\t Address length crossed the limits\t\n");
               properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
               properties.put("mail.pop3s.host", "mycompanyname.com");
               properties.put("mail.pop3s.port", "995");
               properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
               properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
               properties.put("smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
               properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "mycompanyname.com");
               properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
              Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
               protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
                   return new PasswordAuthentication("mymailid.com","mypassword");  
               }  
             });
           try{
                 Folder folder = store.getFolder("inbox");
                 folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
                 if (messages.length != 0) {
                    String from = InternetAddress.toString(message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
                    if (from != null) {
                        System.out.println("From:"  + from);
                    }

                    String to = InternetAddress.toString(message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
                    if (to != null) {
                       System.out.println("To: " + to);             
                    }
                    String subject = message.getSubject();
                    if (subject != null) {
                       System.out.println("Subject: " + subject);
                    }
                       Message forward = new MimeMessage(session);
                       forward.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("mymailid.com"));
                       forward.setSubject("Fwd: " + message.getSubject());
                       forward.addFrom(InternetAddress.parse(from));
                       forward.setFrom(new InternetAddress("mymailid.com"));      
                       MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                       Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                       messageBodyPart.setContent(message.getContent(), "message/rfc822");
                       multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                       forward.setContent(multipart);
                       forward.saveChanges();
                       Transport.send(forward);
                       System.out.println("message forwarded successfully....");
                      }
             catch(Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();  
         }
         }
             }

            System.out.println("\n\n6 close the store and folder objects");    
            emailFolder.close(false);
            store.close();
            } catch (MessagingException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
     }
     }
```